# Google Earth Engine - NDVI time series that excludes two middle years

Tags: google-earth-engine

Please assist me to better capture temporal changes in NDVI using 2000 to 2017 years, where I want to exclude year 2002, and 2005 as these were drought years. If I exclude these will this affect my Mann Kendall analysis to check for monotonic trends?

```js
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD13Q1')
                   .filterDate(ee.Date('2007-11-01'), ee.Date('20117-04-30'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to do it is to manually get three ImageCollections, omitting the years you don't want, and then merge them again into one ImageCollection.

```js
var collection0 = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD13Q1')
                   .filterDate('2000-01-01','2002-01-01');

var collection1 = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD13Q1')
                   .filterDate('2003-01-01','2005-01-01');

var collection2 = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD13Q1')
                   .filterDate('2005-01-01','2018-01-01');

var collection = ee.ImageCollection(collection0
        .merge(collection1).merge(collection2))

print(collection)
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Am working to modify the collections for each year to filter the growing season :  November to April months.